# How to simulate interrupts in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, embedded, simulation, interrupt

I am trying to design an artificial learning unit.  Naturally I want to simulate the model before microcontroller implementation.  The main issue with simulation is  trying to simulate microcontroller sensor interrupts (say with a PIC18).  I'm not so much looking at actually causing an interrupt as I am trying to simulate one with code.

I guess this simply boils down to basic C/C++ info.  Can and if so how do you implement/emulate/simulate interrupts in them?

Comment: What operating system are you developing this under?

Comment: Seems you're putting the cart before the horse here... you need to have a basic working PIC simulator before you'd implement something to check for and simulate interrupts... given the level of this question I'd hazard you're be better off finding an existing simulator, which is likely to have implemented interrupts anyway.

Comment: @TonyD -- I suppose, only I'm just trying to make a mock-up on an actual computer before porting the concept to the PIC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use signals

See here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal

You can use your operational system to send the signals.